# checkbox disappearing when clicked on tablet

Tags: android, checkbox, android-relativelayout

Hello I have a simple application that uses a checklist on of the layouts. Weirdly, the `CheckBox` works great on my Galaxy phone (ANDROID V5.0.1) but for some reason when I use the same application on the tablet(ANDROID V4.2.2) the `CheckBox` disappears when clicked, any ideas would be helpful thank you!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:buttonTint="#0870f8" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit question and add your check listener implementation for the check box. Also please post complete layout file

Comment: close `</RelativeLayout>` in you XML file

Comment: @ShadowDroid I have added my full xml code. The listener implementatio is just used to grab the cell I am using, it does not set the click box this is done automatically with the checkbox object when clicked?

Comment: @ShaishavJogani I had just posted the checkbox code I had the closing brackets already implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just guess because i don't have a tablet here and you didn't provide any information about android version.
I don't think that your checkbox just disappears, try to change background of RelativeLayout to any color (like red or blue) to check if it really disappear.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I added the android information on the question, the galaxy phone uses 5.0.1 and the tablet uses 4.2.2 Thank you for the idea of changing the background it seems the buttonTint attribute does not work on android 4.2.2? Do you have any ideas if there is a similar one to make it work? Thank you again!!

Comment: Thank you for your idea to check it, I did a quick google search, removed the button tint option and added a theme for the checkbox and worked! thank you again for your help!!